# converting a output all to seconds

Tags: python, math

How would I write a program that reads in hours, minutes, and seconds as a input, but then outputs everything in seconds only? For example 1 is the number of hours, 6 is the number of minutes and 40 is the number of seconds, and the output would print out 4000 seconds (that is just a example).

Before I got stuck I really only got the variables for example

`numberSeconds = 40`
`numberMinutes = 6`
`numberHours = 1`

This is kind of all I got, don't even know if its on the right path, I'm new to developing and the math parts has me stuck. Thank you to anyone who sees this!

Answer (score 2):

Well I think you can do this very easy way.

`totalSeconds = numberSeconds + numberMinutes * 60 + numberHours * 3600`

And far the more, if you want to get input from the console.
You can do with this way.

```
numberSeconds = int(input("Enter seconds: "))
numberMinutes = int(input("Enter minutes: "))
numberHours = int(input("Enter hours: "))

totalSeconds = numberSeconds + numberMinutes * 60 + numberHours * 3600

print("Total seconds:", totalSeconds )
```

Answer (score 1):

In every hour there are 60 minutes.

In every minute there are 60 seconds.

Thus, given hours, minutes and seconds, you can find the total amount of seconds by multiplying the amount of hours by 60*60 (3600) and the amount of minutes by 60. Sum the results and the amount of seconds given as input and you will get the total amount of seconds.

Mathemtically this would be:

```
totalSeconds = <hours * 60 * 60> + <minutes * 60> + seconds
```

and is almost identical to how one would solve the question in Python. If you still need help to solve the question, I would recommend following a beginners tutorial in Python to learn a bit of the basic syntax of Python. Alternatively, you can follow the Python Documentation tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

```
hours_in_seconds = numberHours * 3600
minutes_in_seconds = numberMinutes * 60

seconds_total = hours_in_seconds + minutes_in_seconds + numberSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* do the math if you remember that there are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour, the standard [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) class can do it for you.

```py
import datetime

numberHours = int(input("Enter hours: "))
numberMinutes = int(input("Enter minutes: "))
numberSeconds = int(input("Enter seconds: "))

timespan = datetime.timedelta(hours=numberHours, minutes=numberMinutes, seconds=numberSeconds)
totalSeconds = timespan.total_seconds()
```